# Remember me cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how to handle this situation.  I have the following line for logging in a user however with this situation the remember post parameter might not be set upon form submission so i'd still like it to send 0 as its value with this function.

```
if ($this->kowauth->login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'),
                            $this->input->post('remember'))) {}
```

Here's the form element:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['xtrcook']))
{
    echo form_label((form_checkbox('remember', '1', TRUE)) . 'Remember Me!', 'remember');
}
else
{
     echo form_label((form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE)) . 'Remember Me!', 'remember');
}
?>
```

Although drew010 had a good answer its not the route I want to go with this so I'm asking if anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: You must be inventing some complex problem that doesn't exist. For one, `$this->input->post()` will not throw an error if the data isn't there. For two, what @drew010 said is perfect for the alternative (checking $_POST manually). For three, checkboxes only have a SET/UNSET value. So even something as simple as `empty($_POST['remember'])` would work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear.  If the 'remember' parameter isn't set to 1, you know that your user doesn't want to be remembered, so you don't extend the life of their cookie.

In your controller you can easily revert to a default value by using something like this:

```
$remember = ($this->input->post('remember') == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

If they click the checkbox, it'll send 1 as the `$remember` value, if they don't a default value of 0 is used for the variable instead.

Comment: Well what about the set_checkbox function in the docs. I don't quite understand how I could use that in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `hidden` form element before the checkbox with the same name as the checkbox (`remember`), and give the hidden element a value of 0, when the checkbox is not checked, you will get the `0` from the hidden element.  When the checkbox is checked, the `0` from the hidden element will be overwritten by the checkbox.

Example HTML Output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="remember" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="1" /> <label for="remember">Remember Me!</label>
```

If the checkbox is submitted, the hidden element is overwritten, if it is not, then the hidden element's value is sent.

Comment: It's a pretty standard method, otherwise a standard checkbox won't send a value unless it is checked.  You could use some sort of scripted checkbox instead.